# Find value in array for Wordpress template condition

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am using MagicFields in Wordpress with a custom group for Ingredients which is duplicated. The ingredient type field is selected with a radio button.

I am trying to write a conditional statement to only show certain ingredient types (Base, Sauce, etc) so they can be shown in different lists on the page.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
if (in_array('Base', $IngGroup)) {
    echo "Base Ingredients"; 
}
elseif (in_array('Sauce', $IngGroup)) {
    echo "Sauce Ingredients"; 
}
```

Here is the array output from pr($IngGroup);

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [ingredient_type] => Array
            (
                [1] => Main
            )
        [ingredient_unit] => Array
            (
                [1] => g
            )
        [ingredient_amount] => Array
            (
                [1] => 300
            )
        [ingredient_name] => Array
            (
                [1] => Chicken
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [ingredient_type] => Array
            (
                [1] => Sauce
            )
        [ingredient_unit] => Array
            (
                [1] => g
            )
        [ingredient_amount] => Array
            (
                [1] => 220
            )
        [ingredient_name] => Array
            (
                [1] => Sauce
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach( $IngGroup as $Ing ) {
    if( $Ing[ingredient_type][1] == 'Sauce' ) {
        echo "Sauce Ingredients"; 
    } elseif ( $Ing[ingredient_type][1] == 'Base' ) {
        echo "Base Ingredients"; 
    }
}
```